# Wordpress deployment after GCE instance creation using custom image

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I had installed WordPress on a Google Compute Engine instance. In order to move it's region to eu, I recreated a CE VM instance in another project & in eu region, using a custom image from existing disk. WordPress installation seems to be broken now.

I assigned a static IP to new instance, and used the new MySQL database etc in wp-config.php.
I can connect to the VM instance using ssh, and see the Wordpress files deployed.

Earlier, I could see an entry in Deployent Manager in GConsole dashboard, which is not present in new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your issue and, indeed, the configuration is broken.

This is why:
If you created a new vm instance from your custom image, the configuration that Deployment Manager does are not gonna be in your instance.

I recommend that instead of recreating the whole vm instance with a custom image, deploy a new wordpress solution from Marketplace and export/import your current site.

Also, you can go to wordpress support [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/)

Comment: Thanks, your recommendation would have been the better option. But I managed to get my WP site up after setting the firewall rules & DNS manually. I still miss the deployment manager though, and will probably have to live with it.